# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n}{n}\right)^p$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left(\frac{1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n}{n}\right)^p$$ converges if $p>1$ and diverges when $0<p\leqslant1$.

**My attempt**:

Since the terms of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac1n$ are monotonically decreasing and positive, I applied [Cauchy's Condensation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), i.e, if $\sum a(n)$ and $\sum2^na(2^n)$ will converge and diverge together.
Applying this I got, $\sum\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^p$, but I am stuck now. Don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Could you please improve the readibility of your question by using the $\LaTeX$ support? It should be $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n H_n^p}$, I guess.

Comment: I tryed to decode your text. Please check if it is correct

Comment: @AndreasT, yes question is correct and now it is much more readable. Thanks.

Comment: If $p>0$ then the sum is more than $\sum\frac1n$ which diverges.

Comment: @Michael, The series given is ∑1/n(1+1/2+....+1/n)^p and not ∑1/n, so I assume there must be some different concept to solve it.

Comment: If the exponent were $-p$ instead of $p$, then it would converge if $p>1$ and diverge is $p\leq1$

Comment: If we take -p instead of p, how can we show that?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you have a look the proof below. cause I dont understand your formula $\sum\frac{1}{nH^p_n}$

Comment: @GuyFsone: initially it wasn't clear if the question was about $\sum\frac{H_n^p}{n^p}$ or about $\sum\frac{1}{n H_n^p}$, then an edit clarified that. You proof is fine, but of course one does not need the full power of Hardy's inequality to show that $\sum \frac{H_n^p}{n^p}$ is convergent for $p>1$.

Answer (score 6):

On one hand since $\frac {1}{n}\le \frac 1n\left(1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n\right)$ it is not difficult to see that for $p>0$ we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n^p}\le\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left(\frac{1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n}{n}\right)^p$$ so the divergence statement from Riemann series which diverges for $p\le 1$

On the other hand it follows from [Hardy inequality that:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) for $p>1$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n}{n}\right)^p\le \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n^p}<\infty$$
 the converges blatantly follows from the Riemann series on the right hand side which converges only for $p>1.$

Answer (score 3):

By *Riemann sums*, we have $\log n\lt\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1i\lt1+\log n$
This leads to $\sum \frac1n(\log n)^p$, which, by another *Riemann sum*, can be compared with $\int_1^n\frac1x(\log x)^pdx=\int_0^{\log x}y^pdp$

Comment: How does it shows that ∫(y^p)dp converges for p>1 and diverges for p≤1?

Answer (score -1):

In $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n}{n}\right)^p$$

$$1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n=O(\log(n))$$

so , given sum equals

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+\frac 12+\ldots+\frac 1n}{n}\right)^p=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)^p$$

Here, $O(n)\gg O(\log(n))$ ,

so convergence of given sum depends on convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^p$$

which converges if $p>1$ and diverges when $0<p\leq1$.

For case $p=1$

given sum equals $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)$$  which is divergent as

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n(\log^p(n))}\right)$$

converges if $p>1$