# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s$ converges when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n $ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Assume that $a_n\ge0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n $ converges, then

> show that for every $s>1$ the following series converges too:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s.$$

I failed to handle this with Hölder inequality. Any tips or hint will be appreciated.

Also it might be helpful to see that there is a Césaro sum of $(a_n^{1/s})_n$ appearing in the last series.

Comment: Apparently true for $s=-1$ as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599999

Comment: You seemed well-aware of Hardy's inequality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2587394/44121), it is a strange question coming from you.

Comment: @barto patently there must be some gap between $0$ and $1$ : I think one should be able to prove that this failed for $0<s<1. $

Comment: @GuyFsone Indeed, already for $(a_n)=(1,0,0,\ldots)$

Comment: @barto that wise now can we shift backward a bitt to $-1<s<0$?  from this we have more clue for the range of $s$

Comment: @GuyFsone The first two lines of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/600943/43288) show that it converges for $s<0$ and is bounded by $\sum a_n$ up to a factor $e$. One can try to optimize the constant.

Comment: @barto i have completely read the answer but did not found where the general case $s<0$ is mentioned

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please can you help  here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587694/studying-the-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-fraca-11-sa-21-s  it seems to be more interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It converges by [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality):
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a_1^{1/s}+a_2^{1/s}+\cdots +a_n^{1/s}}{n}\right)^s\leq \left(\frac{s}{s-1}\right)^s\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n.$$

Comment: that was perfectly the key point thanks for the wise observation

Comment: Please can you help [ here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587694/studying-the-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-fraca-11-sa-21-s) it seems to be more interesting